# Can you script NuGet's update-package cmdlet to update or reinstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I need to script Visual Studio 2015's Package Manager Console to update a custom package to the latest version, and, if there is no update to that package, reinstall the current version.

something like this

```
$ret = update-package -Id foobar
if ($ret indiciated that no package was updated)
   update-package -Reinstall -Id foobar
```

but I couldn't see any return values from update-package that allow me to do this.

This is part of a workflow where I have many developers updating their projects to the latest known good versions that I control via package foobar's install.ps1 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best I can do is use Get-Package like

```
if ($(Get-Package -Updates|where{$_.Id -eq foobar})) { 
    Update-Package -Id foobar 
}
else {
    Update-Package -Reinstall -Id foobar
}
```